# does the value of pointers change if exception occurs during assignment?

Tags: c++, exception

Consider the following code where `pb` is a member of class `myclass`:

```
myclass& operator=(const myclass& rhs){
    myclass *pOrig = pb;
    pb = new myclass(*rhs.pb);  //exception occurs here .
    delete pOrig;            
    return *this; 
}
```

Will the value of `pb` remain the same or will it change ? Explain.

Comment: A `new` expression will either return a valid pointer or throw (it doesn't throw "during assignment"). So there's your answer.

Comment: The exception does not occur during assignment here. It occurs while evaluating a subexpression of an expression that also contains assignment as another subexpression. To understand what happens, consider the expression `2 + foo()` when `foo()` throws.

Comment: You have confused = and ==

Answer (score 5):

This code

```
pb = new myclass(*rhs.pb);
```

is equivalent to the following:

```
{
    myclass * temp = new myclass(*rhs.pb); //can throw
    pb = temp; //cannot throw
}
```

so if `new` statement throws for any reason (cannot allocate or cannot construct) `pb` value is not changed.

This is why the following code is dangerous if `ptr` persists the value between invokations of the code:

```
// BAD
delete ptr;
ptr = new CoolObject();
```

because if `ptr` was non null and `new` throws then `ptr` now holds an invalid value and running this code again will lead to so-called "double delete" which causes undefined behavior.

The following code avoid that problem:

```
// MUCH BETTER
delete ptr;
ptr = 0;
ptr = new CoolObject();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `new` expression may throw for various reasons. First, you should know the exact semantics of a `new` expression. In your case, it performs the following steps:

1) Allocates storage;
2) Constructs `myclass` in the allocated storage.

If 1) fails, `new` throws directly. If 2) fails, the allocated storage is deallocated first and then throws. In either case, the assignment is not performed at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short program to illustrate your problem statement:

```
#include <iostream>

class A{
public:
    A(){throw 0;}
};

using namespace std;

int main(){
    A* p = reinterpret_cast<A*>(1234);
    try{
        p = new A;
    }catch(...){
        cout << "Caught exception" << endl;
    }
    cout << p << endl << flush;
    return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

```
Caught exception
000004D2
```

As you can see the exception is thrown while the object is being constructed but definitely before the assignment takes place.

Comment: This doesn't prove anything because "what if it's magic which sets the pointer to null in case of exception".